# How setup subdomain in pm2?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx, pm2

I had nodejs app. Run via pm2 and nginx server.

But now I need a change from localhost:8082 server to api.example.com (subdomain).

I did some manipulations and now it is totally broke.

So, I started from the beginning.

I have a folder with nodejs code. I have env variables so I created an ecosystem by `pm2 ecosystem`
ecosystem:

```
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    script: 'app.js',
    watch: '.',
env: {
            "PORT": 3000,
            "NODE_ENV": "development"
        },
        env_production: {
            "PORT": 81,
            "NODE_ENV": "production",
        }
  }],

  deploy : {
    production : {
      user : 'SSH_USERNAME',
      host : 'SSH_HOSTMACHINE',
      ref  : 'origin/master',
      repo : 'GIT_REPOSITORY',
      path : 'DESTINATION_PATH',
      'pre-deploy-local': '',
      'post-deploy' : 'npm install && pm2 reload ecosystem.config.js --env production',
      'pre-setup': ''
    }
  }
};
```

Then I run  `pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --env production`

pm2 logs:

```
PM2      | App [app:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [app:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [app:0] online
0|app    | WARNING: NODE_APP_INSTANCE value of '0' did not match any instance config file names.
0|app    | WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
0|app    | Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::80
0|app    |     at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1313:16)
0|app    |     at listenInCluster (net.js:1361:12)
0|app    |     at Server.listen (net.js:1447:7)
0|app    |     at Function.listen (/var/www/backend/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
0|app    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/backend/app.js:109:5)
0|app    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
0|app    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
0|app    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
0|app    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
0|app    |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/ProcessContainerFork.js:32:23)
0|app    |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
0|app    |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1157:10)
0|app    |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:985:32)
0|app    |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:878:14)
0|app    |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
0|app    |     at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
0|app    |   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
0|app    |   errno: 'EADDRINUSE',
0|app    |   syscall: 'listen',
0|app    |   address: '::',
0|app    |   port: 80
0|app    | }
PM2      | App [app:0] exited with code [1] via signal [SIGINT]
PM2      | App [app:0] starting in -fork mode-
PM2      | App [app:0] online
```

So, I see it is trying to start on 80 port
But I need it start on subdomain: **api.example.com**

I'm totally confused

Comment: Dealing with domains/subdomains is usually an nginx job (you need to setup the correct backend to proxy the incoming request depending on HTTP `Host` header value / request URI), but before you proceed to nginx setup you need to sort out why your node app tries to listen port 80 rather than 81.

Comment: @IvanShatsky I did this from the beginning and post a new question with full details, Maybe you can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64898424/how-setup-subdomain-in-nginx