# How setup subdomain in nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx, subdomain, nginx-config, nginx-location

I tried a few times do from the beginning but still, my subdomain doesn't work.
I have ubuntu Nginx. I want to create a client-side and backend(subdomain) domain.

The client-side config(work correctly):

```
server {
        root  /var/www/html/dist;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html;

        server_name hookahscope.com www.hookahscope.com;

        location ~ ^/(sitemap.xml) {
            root /var/www/html/public;
        }
        location / {
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/chain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.hookahscope.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = hookahscope.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name hookahscope.com www.hookahscope.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

**UPDATED:**
My client side(main domain) config has additional configs and this is the conflict

```
server {
    if ($host = www.hookahscope.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = hookahscope.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
    server_name www.api.hookahscope.com api.hookahscope.com; # managed by Certb>
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/fullchain.pem; # mana>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/privkey.pem; # ma>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/chain.pem; # >
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot

}



server {
    if ($host = www.api.hookahscope.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = api.hookahscope.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name www.api.hookahscope.com api.hookahscope.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

And back-end config:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        root  /var/www/backend;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html;

        server_name api.hookahscope.com;

location ~ ^/(sitemap.xml) {
    root /var/www/html/public;
}

        location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri /index.html;
        }

}
```

I run backend on pm2(server is nodejs with express)
So, locally I can see backend on 8081 port by command :

```
 curl http://localhost:8081/
```

Nginx show some error, but it is not helped me:

```
 sudo nginx -t
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "api.hookahscope.com" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
```

Of course, the error disappear if remove listen 80; from the subdomain config, but I can't find what I should setup instead of

**UPDATED2**
My subdomain config:

```
server {
        server_name api.hookahscope.com;

#location ~ ^/(sitemap.xml) {
 #   root /var/www/html/public;
#}

        location / {
proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/fullchain.pem; # mana>
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/privkey.pem; # ma>
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/chain.pem; # >
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: try this `proxy_pass http://localhost:8081/;`

Comment: Both `proxy_pass` and `try_files` (as well as the `fastcgi_pass`, `uwsgi_pass` etc) are so-called *content handlers*. You should have only one content handler per `location` block, using several content handlers at once is meaningless and could lead to unpredictable results. Your nginx error means you have several `server` blocks with `server_name api.hookahscope.com; listen 80;` directives. You should check the `nginx -T` output to check what additional configuration files are being included to the main nginx config. Or better add that command output to your question.

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan Yes, you are right, now see Cannot GET /index.html so need to do something else

Comment: @IvanShatsky I found this conflict. Actually my main(client side) config has lines for subdomain. I updated my post. So now I'm not use remove it, or remove my api.hookahscope.com config.

Comment: @Mediator Are `hookahscope.com`, `www.hookahscope.com` and `api.hookahscope.com` the only domain names served by this particular nginx instance or there are some other shared server blocks/domain names? What domain names are actually listed under SAN (subject alternative name) field of the SSL certificate? What was the `certbot` command issued for getting those? In general you should never allow certbot to made any nginx automatic configuration change, I wrote about it [just yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64889800/certbot-nginx-generates-pr-end-of-file-error/64890313#64890313).

Comment: @Mediator And before I suggest you an optimal configuration for this case, answer one more question, do you want for some www-to-non-www or non-www-to-www redirection to be added to that configuration? As for now you have non-www HTTP to non-www HTTPS and www HTTP to www HTTPS redirection automatically added by certbot.

Comment: Relly Im don't care about rediretion from www to non-www, the most important all domains should work www non-www with http or https.

Comment: @Mediator What about my previous questions? Are `hookahscope.com`, `www.hookahscope.com` and `api.hookahscope.com` the only domain names served by this particular nginx instance or there are some other shared server blocks/domain names?

Comment: @IvanShatsky only hookahscope.com www.hookahscope.com and api.hookahscope.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the `Host` HTTP header via the `if ($host = hookahscope.com) { ... }` I recommend to filter the requests defining two `server` blocks as [suggested](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#server-name-if) by official nginx documentation (read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362642/nginx-doesnt-listen-on-port-80-twice/60362700#60362700) answer for detailed description). Having two separate SSL `server` blocks you shouldn't use the `ipv6only=on` flag on `listen` directive (read [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/638367/do-you-need-separate-ipv4-and-ipv6-listen-directives-in-nginx) thread for details). Here is the configuration I recommend to use:

```
server {
    # redirect HTTP to HTTPS for requests where the HTTP 'Host' header equal to one of our domains
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name hookahscope.com www.hookahscope.com api.hookahscope.com;
    return 301 https://$http_host$request_uri;
}
server {
    # close the connection immediately for the rest of requests
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    return 444;
}
server {
    # frontend
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name hookahscope.com www.hookahscope.com;
    root /var/www/html/dist;

    # SSL configuration made by certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/privkey.pem; managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/chain.pem; managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot

    location = /sitemap.xml {
        root /var/www/html/public;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}
server {
    # backend
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name api.hookahscope.com;

    # SSL configuration made by certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/privkey.pem; managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/hookahscope.com/chain.pem; managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_stapling_verify on; # managed by Certbot

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: this config shows content from hookahscope.com by https://api.hookahscope.com

Comment: also hookahscope.com redirect to the backend. maybe I did something wrong, try to do it from the begging

Comment: @Mediator You can check how the redirections working with `curl` (look at `Location` HTTP header value): `curl http://hookahscope.com`, `curl http://www.hookahscope.com`, `curl http://api.hookahscope.com`. Remember that unlike temporary 302, permanent 301 redirections are being cached by the browser.

Comment: curl http://hookahscope.com and curl http://www.hookahscope.com curl http://api.hookahscope.com returns backend.

Comment: @Mediator Use the markdown (single backquotes) please for URLs, I don't understand anything from the previous comments.

Comment: @Mediator Do you remove all the other `server` blocks? What `nginx -t` says?

Comment: nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "api.hookahscope.com" on 0.0.0.0:443, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "api.hookahscope.com" on [::]:443, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: @Mediator You still have some other `server` blocks in your config from your older configuration. Can you post `nginx -T` output somewhere (append to your question or at pastebin etc)?

Comment: In your config was wrong "hookahscope.com www.hookahscope.com api.hookahscope.com" should be without api.hookahscope.com. Now it is works, but only for https:// but not redirection for htttp://hookahscope.com/ error: curl: (7) Failed to connect to hookahscope.com port 80: Connection refused
"

Comment: @Mediator Nothing was wrong with my config. That `server` block was designed specially for HTTP to HTTPS redirection and should contain all the three domain names (and do a correct redirection for all of them). You have some extra `server` block either in `nginx.conf` or in one of the included files. Can you post `nginx -T` output somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224816/discussion-between-mediator-and-ivan-shatsky).